# how can I use a html input tag inside of the action.link

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to make a Html.Actionlink() that receive something and put it in a new tab, the problem is that the button is a input type.
I have the input like this,
`<input  type="submit" class="btnText" id="previewButton2" value="Preview" />`
What I'm doing in the input do it in the ActionLink, but it's not working and I don't Know Why.`@Html.ActionLink("Preview", "/", new { Id=Model.Id}, new { @class = "btnText", type = "submit", target = "_blank" })`

How can I use the input tag in the ActionLink or what should I do that maybe work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your only option using your existing code would be to submit the form using Javascript onclick (**but that isn't really good practice)**

What you should really do is style your `input` button so that it looks like your `a` tag, then you can alleviate the need to use JavaScript to do what you need.